# $watch not called when model property changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, watch

I am just starting with angular and trying to understand `$watch` function in scope API. Here is a link to my JS fiddle :

[JS Fiddle Watch demo Not working](http://jsfiddle.net/jforjava1981/kn40tp2x/34/)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp1', []);
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
         angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp1']);    
});
function MyController($scope){
         var mc = this;
         mc.focus = {
            'name' :false,
            'email':false
           };

   $scope.$watch(mc.focus,function(oldVal,newVal){
     console.log(oldVal);
     console.log(newVal);
    },false);
    mc.allFilled = false;
    mc.setFocus = function(prop) {
       mc.focus[prop] = true;
    };
};    
myApp.controller("MyController",MyController);
```

What I want to do :

1) I have 4 inputs have included just one in above link for brevity and demo.

2) each of the inputs has corresponding keys in focus object with initial values as false.

3) I will be changing the  property value to true in focus object  whenever appropriate input element is focused using `setFocus()` function

4) as soon as all properties in focus object have truthy values I want to change `allFilled` property to true.

What I am trying to do here :
For achieving what I want to do I am watching focus object and in the listener I will be checking if all properties have value true. If yes I will change the allFilled property/or do other stuff as well.

I know maybe I can execute above logic in `setFocus()` itself but want to try `$watch`.
 1)Is it possible doing this using `$watch`?
 2) Why my `$watch` is not called?
 3)What is the best way to do this in Angular?

Comment: Any answers for my 3rd question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two errors in the code.

1. A the scope.$watch documentation says, the first argument can only be **string** or **function**. You are not supposed to pass variables, unless their value is one of these.
2. Since you are watching changes in the object properties, the third argument to $watch should be set to **true**:

false - compares object by refenece equality, eg. oldVal === newVal. Since the object is the same, changes are not found.

true - looks for changes in all properties in the object. Since the values of properties are changed, the watcher will be fired.

Comment: Is this best way to do such thing in angular.is what I am doing is answer to my 3rd question:)?

Comment: In my opinion it is hard to say if it is the right way. It certainly is the Angular 1.x way, however the creators of the framework argue that it is the wrong way, and created the 2.0 version. In bigger programs the number of watchers grows which causes the performance to drop, so there is strong incentive to use events, such as 'focus', where possible. On the other hand, brevity may suffer, and the code in the example isn't large enough to worry.

Comment: Code in example is not large.however the real example has at least 4 fields. So wats the alternate way to do this if not $watch

Comment: Shall I listen to focus event then.if yes then I will have to create a directive as we should not write event listeners in controllers correct?

Answer (score 1):

The watch expects a string expression, like this:

```
$scope.$watch('mc.focus' ,function(oldVal,newVal){
    console.log(oldVal);
    console.log(newVal);
},false);
```

Now it will run.

You need to set an `ng-model` on the input as well to make this work.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kn40tp2x/46/

Comment: @Chrillwoodz no it doesn't. Can you please post a updated js fiddle modifying the js fiddle I provided

Comment: @ShaileshVaishampayan Hang on, it just worked for me, not sure what I changed before updating.

Comment: I am trying on my mobile.the initial alert comes in the new jsfiddle link I updated.but when I set focus on input the alert does't come.is my new jsfiddle working on your browser.

Comment: @ShaileshVaishampayan No because it's the wrong way of doing it. I have provided the fiddle which you have to use. You need to have a ng-model on the input, look in the fiddle and you will see.

Comment: I got it. Just hegemon pointed out last property should be true. Now it works. http://jsfiddle.net/kn40tp2x/48/

Comment: Is this best way to do such thing in angular.is what I am doing is answer to my 3rd question:)?

Comment: @ShaileshVaishampayan This is how you watch for changes on an input yes, but you can omit the 3rd parameter of the watch.

Comment: No I don't think we need to have ng model on the input my latest fiddle works without that but by changing last property to true.

Comment: @ShaileshVaishampayan I'm sure you can do it in other ways but from what I've read it's best to use ng-model.

Comment: Actually focus object is not part of view.its internal property.so I don't want to bind it in view.is my assumption corrcet?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is you haven't linked your input element to any scope object. It should be.

```
<input type="text" ng-focus="mc.setFocus('name')" ng-model="mc.focus" />
  {{mc.allFilled}}
  {{mc.focus}}
</div>
```

The ng-focus method only gets called whenever focus is set on the input, it says nothing about what is linked to the i
As @Chrillewoodz pointed out, it's supposed to be a string, but it's good to have a ng-model on the input anyway.